# Error al conectar con base de datos MYSQL con java - Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connection" is null

Tags: java, mysql

Buen días Developers,

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en JAVA que me permita listar los datos que tengo almancenados en una DB que tengo en MySql, tengo un problema debido a que al momento de ejecutar el proyecto me sale un error que dice: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connection" is null". Llevo un par de días validando la conexión y la instancia, no comprendo por qué me reconoce la variable connection como null, si al parecer la estoy instanciando bien, ¿Alguna idea?

```
public class Conexion {
public static Connection conectarDB(){
    try {
        String dbDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "javaejemplo1";

        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";

        Class.forName(dbDriver);
        Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + dbName, dbUser, dbPassword);
        return conex;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
        return (Connection) ex.fillInStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
private static final String SQL = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
@Override
public List<Usuario> listar() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Usuario usuario = null;
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    try{
        connection = Conexion.conectarDB();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            int usuario_id = rs.getInt("Id");
            String usuario_name = rs.getString("Nombre");
            String usuario_email = rs.getString("Correo");
            String usuario_password = rs.getString("Contrasena");

            usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setId(usuario_id);
            usuario.setNombre(usuario_name);
            usuario.setEmail(usuario_email);
            usuario.setPassword(usuario_password);

            usuarios.add(usuario);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    return usuarios;

}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código como texto en lugar de usar screenshots. Haz el recorrido (está en el footer) para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Lo peor que pudiste hacer fue retornar `null` en el `try...catch` sin ni siquiera imprimir lo que estaba pasando. Tu mismo te pusiste una venda en los ojos ignorando el error del catch. Por favor, antes de ese `return null`, mínimo agrega un `ex.printStackTrace();` para ver cual es la verdadera causa del problema. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537730/edit) y agrega el `StackTrace` para determinar que es lo que pasa. Por favor, TODO A TEXTO, ni un screenshot más.

Comment: Sumando a la pedido de poner el código como texto, con [formato](/help/formatting): Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: Gracias por poner tu código a texto. Ahora, antes del `return null`, coloca `ex.printStackTrace();`. Luego ejecuta tu código y adjunta en tu pregunta el mensaje de error que te sale. No es hacer `return (Connection) ex.fillInStackTrace();`.

Comment: Hola Jaime, muchas gracias por la recomendación, acabo de realizar la modificación del código, eliminando el return null, por return (Connection) ex.fillInStackTrace(); el tema es que al utilizar el mètodo ex.printStackTrace(); me registra un error cuya acción recomendada me modifica el tipo de función de public static Connection conectarDB() a  public static Object conectarDB()

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tirará por el catch y devuelve null como has especificado.
Debugguea a ver que error sale en el catch.

Revisa tambien el nombre el nombre de clase del driver. "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Drive" ese "cj" parece extraño.